# Is Schrödinger's cat a problem of how we define identity?

Tags: paradox, quantum-physics, identity, quantum-interpretations, emergence

If we consider that a cat is composed of numerous atomic particles, defining particles in superposition presents no issue. A cat is a human construct to represent a grouping of atoms, and notions of life or death emerge from atomic behavior. . For instance, a single-celled bacterium is alive, but if you separate the macromolecules that combined to create the bacterium, these units are not alive. Since life is an emergent property, there's no contradiction in the cat being alive or not. Everything, including ourselves, is quantum. Consider a house made of bricks—when organized, it's a house, but they remain bricks. This underscores that observers, cats, and what we perceive as "classical" are emergent properties of an underlying quantum and elementary world. We label a certain group of atoms as living, as in the case of a live cat. If we consider everything as quantum, paradoxes like Schrodinger’s cat and Wigner's friend dissolve.

Comment: See Decio Krause papers about identity in QM.

Comment: 1. These are "analogies" to explain the (logical) paradox of being "true and false" (at the same time) ..to "living beings", which (obviously) occurs as in "quantum physics" as in "real life"... (They are not paradoxes, which should explain life/identity with quantum physics. ..the contradiction is not in "the cat being alive *or* not" (this is a tautology), but "the cat is alive *and* not" )

Comment: "composed of numerous atomic particles" ...and a "human construct" (there are no alternative (valid) considerations (possible))?

Comment: "if you separate the macromolecule" ...it depends with what organ you "separate": "hands/feet/extremities" or "brain/heart"!? ;)

Comment: No Schrodinger's cat is only problem for "animal rights"...but it's "ok", since/as long theoretical ..

Answer (score 3):

1. The idea of Schroedinger’s cat is not about the concept of
   **identity**.
2. Instead, Schroedinger wanted to show that the superposition of two
   states, a standard situation in quantum mechanics, leads to
   paradoxical conclusions on the macro-level. He questions the
   superposition of the two states “cat live” and  “cat dead”, each
   with probability ½, also on the macroscopic level. On the macro
   level it is senseless to consider a superposition of a dead cat and
   a live cat. And in particular, to determine just by the act of
   observation whether the cat is live or dead.
3. A possible solution to the paradox is the mechanism of *decoherence*: During the transition from the quantum state to the state on the
   macro level, the coherence of the original psi-function get’s lost
   and the resulting psi-function has no longer the capability to
   interfere.

   Anyhow Schroedinger’s cat and its explanation is not
   simple. For an introduction see [Schroedinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat).

Comment: When I was a kid Jiffypop stovetop popcorn came from the store in a pie pan with aluminum foil on top. During cooking the foil starts out flat, there is no sound of kernels popping, and then the pop sounds increase in frequency while the foil rises into a dome shape, and eventually the popping frequency goes back to zero with the foil dome filled with popped popcorn. Particle decay inside the box, that kills the cat, would be like one silent spontaneous popcorn pop but with no statistical model for the single decay event. The cat is alive or dead. But we don't know due to "pop" uncertainty.

Comment: An answer rather than just a comment?

Comment: @Geoffrey Thomas The answer is "No", see point 1. - But I wanted to add also some constructive  statements about this worldfamous cat >:-)

Answer (score 2):

The SC thought experiment was intended to highlight what some physicists- including Schroedinger- considered unsatisfactory about quantum mechanics, which was the idea that particles could have properties that did not take specific values until they were 'measured' or 'observed'. That raised the question of what constituted a measurement/observation and what was so special about it.  Schroedinger's point was that the cat in the box is either alive or dead, and if you opened the box to find a stone-cold rigid feline corpse, you knew for sure that the atom had decayed some hours ago. Whatever degree of uncertainty that had existed at the start of the experiment had resolved itself long before anyone 'measured' or 'observed' events by opening the box. The lesson from the SC thought experiment is that a 'measurement' just meant an interaction between the particle being observed and a bunch of other particles forming the detector. You have to bear in mind that all kinds of whacky ideas about the role of measurement have been put forward by people (including, notably, Wigner, who thought human consciousness played a role in triggering results of experiments). SC has been endlessly mis-represented and sensationalised-  *'Quantum theory proves cats are both alive and dead'*. If you like, you can pander to that nonsense by trying to find a way to square it with the fact that individual particles comprising the cat can be modelled with wave-functions that are superpositions, but why bother?

Comment: Actually, the naive interpretation of QM states that the cat has to remain in the state of superposition — i. e. both dead and alive — until observed. To see why, we have to go back to the double-slit experiment. It shows that a single particle is somehow aware that both slits are open and adjusts its trajectory accordingly. In the naive interpretation, this happens because the particle state undefined, it fills the entire Universe, passing through *both* slits and only collapsing onto a specific location upon hitting the screen/detector — that is, upon getting observed.

Comment: The Quantum Hamiltonian doesn't have gravity in it, so it must really prove that the cat who is alive and dead is definitely floating around inside the box.

Comment: Being mis-represented and sensationalized doesn't imply there's no point to squaring the fact that macroscopic superposition is predicted by QM but not found in real life.  The "why bother?" Is because the investigation led to the theory of decoherence and advances in quantum optics and computing.  I wouldn't call it pandering to nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution to the issue of Schrodinger's cat (SC) isn't clear to me, but I will describe the only solution I've seen to this problem that makes any sense. In the SC thought experiment a cat C and radioactive atom A are in a box along with a measurement device D attached to a poison vial V. If the atom decays the detector measures it, breaks the poison vial and the cat dies. So the state of the total system after one half life is in a superposition and in one branch of the superposition the cat is alive and in the other it's dead. People get confused about this and think it means the cat is alive and dead at the same time.

In reality, any physical system that interacts with the outside world and transfers information about a physical quantity X to it becomes unable to undergo quantum interference between the values of X: this is called decoherence. So then effectively there are multiple versions of the system one for each possible value of X and they are dynamically isolated from one another. This is commonly called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory but it is just a consequence of the unmodified equations of motion of quantum theory and the standard sorts of ways we talk about large scale emergent structures:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

So there are versions of SC, one is alive and the other is dead. In any particular you will only see one of them because of decoherence.